# What's wrong with my code? The file directory exists and yet it says it doesn't

Tags: discord.js

So I've been making a discord bot and have been trying to register slash commands but it keeps giving me the error:

```
node:internal/fs/utils:348
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir 'C:\Users\Neon\Desktop\TestBot\commands'
```

My code is

```
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const commandsDir = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');

if (!fs.existsSync(commandsDir)) {
  console.error(`The 'commands' directory is missing at: ${commandsDir}`);
  process.exit(1);
}
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);

    const data = await rest.put(
      Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
      { body: commands },
    );

    console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

I've checked the directory several times and it does exist and works when I input it into file explorer and the `commands` file is in the same folder as `deploycommands.js`.

I've tried other suggestions from a few other sites but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well try using this

```js
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("/commands/").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"))

//and then the commandFiles will return the array
```

In this way, it will takes the directory in the same file the code ran on